# Language of iPad App Store incorrect, not matching language settings

Tags: ipad, language

Using an iPad Air (2021 version ?) running iPadOS 16.4, I cannot set French (or English) as language for the App Store.
The iPad is furthermore French and the region is set to France. All apps are French, which is correct, but the App store is Dutch and I cannot change that. Is that because my IP address is in the Netherlands ?

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings > App Store > Language? And setting the language to english or french?

Comment: Yes, it is set to French, but it shows the App Store in Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with another app before and I found fixes for this (the 3rd one worked for me because it's the one I did first) :

1. Reboot and try again
2. Change overall iPhone language and back. Go to Settings > General > Language & Region and choose "Nederlands (Dutch)". It will need to reboot to change the language. Then, do the same thing but change it back to english. This will change the overall iPad language to Dutch, so that the App Store will be in accord with the rest of the iPad, then, changing it back to english might make the App Store change.
3. 3rd and most likely : Change the App Store language to Dutch and back. Go to Settings > App Store > Language and change it to Dutch, open App Store and quit it, then change it to English again and reopen App Store. About the same explanation than the possible fix 2.